# frame inside of iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

I have this enviroment:

Page1.html:

```
<iframe id="ifr" name="nifr" src="Page2.html" enableviewstate="true" width="800" height="600" frameborder="1" style="z-index:0" ><p>Su navegador no soporta iframes.</p></iframe>
```

Page2.html:

```
<frameset rows="30,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <frame id="titleFrame" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="title.html">
    <frame id="viewerFrame" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="anotherPage.html">
</frameset>
```

How can I get the frame "viewerFrame" with javascript? I'm working only on internet explorer

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using frames, iframes and IE. Sounds like a satanic ritual.

Comment: Get the iframe from what level?

Comment: @OhCaN I know, and can't do anything, "Page2.html" is not my webpage, I have to make a miracle :S

Comment: @epascarello get the **frame** of Page2.html, Page2.html is inside of Page1.html as a **iframe**. Kinda tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll add a `name`-attribute for the frame-elements.

```
<frameset rows="30,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
<frame name="titleFrame" id="titleFrame" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="title.html">
<frame name="viewerFrame" id="viewerFrame" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="anotherPage.html">
</frameset>
```

Then you can try this from Page1.html:

`var viewerFrame=document.getElementById('ifr').contentWindow.viewerFrame;`

Comment: Hm... You could have mentioned about this in your question: "Page2.html is not my webpage". You'll really need a miracle... That means, you can't get any kind of acces to the frameset, if you won't have rights to edit Page2.html.

Comment: I tried your snippet code, but I get "undefined" D: **EDIT:** I understand, specially when in Page2 I have just a frame, thanks for your help

Comment: @NatyBizz Yep, that was expected, after your comment to OhCaN. Like I said in my comment to my own answer, there is no way to access the third-party website, if you're not be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you are probably searching something like that:

```
$("#ifr").contentWindow.$("#viewerFrame").html();
```